# Parallel programming in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, parallel-processing

I made wcf service  which i hosted in web role in azure. The instance of the role is extra large (it's just one instance), it has 8 cores.I have two methods in the service. The methods are calculating matrix multiplication, one of them with sequential programming, the other with parallel (using the Parallel.For)
The result is that the sequential programming is faster than the parallel. Am i doing something wrong?
I was monitoring the processor work, and when i start the parallel calculation, all cores are used, but the result isn't better...
Here is the code for the parallel programming matrix multiplication

```
ParallelOptions p = new ParallelOptions();
            p.MaxDegreeOfParallelism=8; 
 Parallel.For(0, n,p, i =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {

                        suma = 0;


                        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                        {

                            suma = (matricaA[i, k] * matricaB[k, j]);

                        }
                        proizvod[i, j] = suma;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hmm, might need to see all the code, including Serial. I can only imagine your code isn't running what you think it is.

Comment: I tested the code before deploying to Azure on my local machine, and it works nice...

Comment: Hmm, well that certainly is very unusual then. We run large-scale parallel workloads on 4 & 8 core instances in Azure and the expected speedup is most certainly there. If it was me, I'd try another super simple parallel vs serial scenario and see if this exhibits the same behavior. I'd put some logging in to try and understand the path of execution better. It might also be worth trying this on a 4 core machine where you're only executing on 1 quad core socket - rather that across the two with 8 cores.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact cause to the problem. But here's my suggestion: Use remote desktop to login to the cloud machine. Create a console application that performs the matrix computation in parallel. Then run the console application on the cloud machine. Use resource monitor to check CPU usage. If CPU usage often approaches 100%, then you can be confident the code logic is correct.

Since you're using WCF, be aware that WCF by default can handle multiple requests using mutiple threads at the same time. So it is possible that your server is computing multiple matrixes at the same time, instead of computing a single matrix using multiple threads. Usually computation heavy jobs are done on worker roles without WCF, where they're performed one by one.

Comment: i made the console app, like you suggested me, and i was monitoring the CPU usage, and it uses 100% when i set the number of threads to 8, about 50% when set to 4 threads... I can't find what is the problem... Is there any problem with my code? Thanks...\

Comment: Thanks to everyone that tried to help me, i solved the problem. Following this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx. i moved the code for matrix multiplication in another function (just like in the example) and called in the main function, and i got the wanted results.